# How to store and update steps count data with Date wise in firebase

Tags: android, firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore

I'm working on a step counting app. I want to store user data `userGoal`, `userSteps` day wise and I want to update that data dynamically in Firebase Firestore.

I created array of objects to store and update users everyday data, I search about it but showing we can't update data with specific index from the array in Firestore.

Any other way to store and update users everyday data with Date?

This I created a Firestore structure array of an object:

[image: this I created a Firestore structure array of object]

Comment: The Firebase Realtime Database and Cloud Firestore are two separate databases. Please only mark your question with the relevant tag, not with both.

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend storing the daily aggregates in a map, instead of in an array. By storing them as a map, you can update the count for the current day using a dictionary.

So in JSON/dot notation it'd look like:

```
allDay: {
  "2020-07-29": {
    "userGoal": 1000,
    "userStep": 0
  },
  "2020-07-31": {
    "userGoal": 1000,
    "userStep": 0
  }
}
```

You can then update the right element with a dictionary, or by [using `.` notation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#update_fields_in_nested_objects):

```
db.collection("user").document("uidOfTheUser")
        .update(
                "userGoal", 1500,
                "allDat.2020-07-31.userGoal", 1500
        );
```